# EF 5 Connection Strings + Simple Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to clean up my web.config file as there seems to be redundancy in the connection string department. However, I can't seem to whittle it down to only being one.

Here is what I have:
This is a Database First scenario.

My Context code:

```
public partial class InventoryMgmtContext : DbContext
{
    public InventoryMgmtContext()
        : base("name=InventoryMgmtContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
  ...
}
```

My connection string in web.config that corresponds to InventoryMgmtContext:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="InventoryMgmtContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InventoryMgmt.InventoryMgmt.csdl|res://*/InventoryMgmt.InventoryMgmt.ssdl|res://*/InventoryMgmt.InventoryMgmt.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=<SERVER_NAME>;initial catalog=<DB_NAME>;persist security info=True;user id=<UID>;password=<PWD>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=OTIS_InvnMgmt&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I was hoping that was all I would need, but then I saw that I also have the following connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=<SERVER_NAME>;Initial Catalog=OTIS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<UID>;Password=<PWD>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=OTIS_InvnMgmt" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I have the following for the Membership and Role providers in my web.config that refer to the DefaultConnection string:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Finally, the initialization has the following:

```
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {

                try
                {
                    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                    {
                        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
                        //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("InventoryMgmtContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I changed the Role and Membership Provider to point to the InventoryMgmtContext string instead, and that works, but if I change the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabase to use InventoryMgmtContext (from the original DefaultConnection), like:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("InventoryMgmtContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
```

I get the following error:

```
"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."
```

I have searched for "DefaultConnection" throughout the project, and cannot find where or how this is being referenced.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you "using" System.Data in the code where you defined InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute?  I'm not very familiar with the System.Data.EntityClient namespace but my guess is the initialization process does not like that as compared to System.Data.SqlClient...

Comment: Have you got '<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true"/>' in your web.config?